# wmic dont likes the variable im using

Tags: windows, powershell

I made this code to kill a task. With Get-VBRJob i get all the backup jobs and their ID, then I isolate the job name imput, then filter just leave the ID and last it delete the header. This variable result is not working on the wmic command im using. I guess i need to convert the variable content in something?. Thanks!

```
$JobName = Read-Host "Enter Job name"
$JobID = Get-VBRJob | select name, ID | Where {$_.name -like $JobName} | select ID | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%$JobID%'" Call Terminate
```

Comment: Does $jobid contain what you think it does?

Comment: Yes, if you do $JobID before wmic it contains the necessary and correct value. And the wmic line alone works too

Comment: I guess you just need the ID: `$JobID = (Get-VBRJob | Where {$_.name -like $JobName}).ID`

Comment: @CritScratch - you have this horrible abomination >>> `Format-Table` <<< in your code. that should NEVER be used for anything other than _final_ output to screen OR final output to a plain text file. use `Select-Object` instead so that you get _objects_ instead of _formatting data_.

Comment: @js2010 that did the trick, thank you! and thanks also to the rest of you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's blank lines above and below the id. I think you want

```
| select -expand id
```

instead with no format-table. And the id must appear in the commandline. You wouldn't normally store format-table output to a variable.

Btw, instead of wmic, you can use

```
get-wmiobject win32_process | where commandline -match $jobid | remove-wmiobject
```